# Errors when installing grunt-cli with npm

Tags: node.js, npm, gruntjs, npm-install

Since today, our project is having problems when doing the npm installation of the grunt-cli. We have specificed the following versions of the grunt packages in the package.json:

```
"grunt": "~0.4.0",
"grunt-cli": "^1.2.0"
```

The error that occurs, is the following:

```
[ERROR] module.js:327
[ERROR]     throw err;
[ERROR]     ^
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Error: Cannot find module '/myproject/node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt'
[ERROR]     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
[ERROR]     at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
[ERROR]     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
[ERROR]     at startup (node.js:139:18)
[ERROR]     at node.js:974:3
```

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this problem? We didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have some little issue with your **node_modules**, you might have to delete the **node_modules** dir completely, then run your `npm install` again to have your required modules install again.

This should fix your problem.

Comment: This is being done automatically everytime a new build is triggered, so this should not be the problem. Maybe the grunt version is too old?

Comment: yea, it should be done automatically, but sometimes if by chance you get any interruption from the network, some modules will fail to install. and running `npm install` should install the `grunt` you required in your package.json

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a problem with your `grunt-cli`. Can you please try to remove the same and install it again. You can run the following commands.

```
npm remove -g grunt grunt-cli
```

And

```
npm install -g grunt grunt-cli
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `grunt-cli` from your `package.json` and install it globally and grunt itself can stay in project context.

```
npm install grunt-cli -g
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was apparently caused by something else entirely. We changed our UI project version to x.x.x-SNAPSHOT and now it works fine.